# Fecting records from the database using the value in a selection box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Please, help me out to solve the following problem.
I have a web page that takes some information from the user. I have loaded all the Member IDs to a select box, which a member can select their own Member ID easily. My problem is, I want to display automatically the first name and the Last name of the that particular user once his/her Member ID is selected. I know that I require Javascript or Jquery with PHP and MySql, But I don't know how to use it properly. Part of the coding is as follows.

//loads Member ID to a select box

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');
$sqlselect = "SELECT MemID FROM Member" ;
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sqlselect);
<?
```

//displaying membr ID in select box

```
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form action="bookrequestmem.php" method="post"> 
<label for="memberid">Member ID:</label><br>
<select id="memid" name="memid1">  
            <option>Select Member ID</option>";
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
            <option><?php echo $row[0];?></option>";
            <?php endwhile;?>
 </select>
 <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
 <Input type="text" name="memfname"/>
 <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
 <Input type="text" name="memlname"/>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please tell me how to disply the First name and the Last name automatically when the proper Member ID is selected.

Comment: You can use jquery's change method on select and fetch the value of the option selected and then send to other page using jquery ajax to query first name and last name of the member whose id is selected.

Comment: @programmingArrow hi, yes I know that I can use an event like onchange() with select box. [<select id="memid" name="memid1" onchange(getvalue)>], but then please tell me how to use jquery to get the first name and last name from database table

Comment: Heres the link for change method, you can read and try https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp

Comment: thanks... i'll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Smart Way without AJAX**

```js
   function get_meminfo()
   {
    var dt=($("#memid").val()).split("~~");
    $("#memfname").val(dt[1]);
    $("#memlname").val(dt[2]);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form action="bookrequestmem.php" method="post"> 
<label for="memberid">Member ID:</label><br>
<select id="memid" name="memid1" onChange="get_meminfo()">  
            <option>Select Member ID</option>";
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
            <option value="MEM_ID~~FIRST_NAME~~LAST_NAME">Test MEM ID</option>";
            <?php endwhile;?>
 </select>
 <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
 <Input type="text" name="memfname" id="memfname" />
 <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
 <Input type="text" name="memlname" id="memlname"/>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#memid").change(function(){
                var id = $("#memid").val();

                 $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'getname.php',
                            data: {id: id},
                            success: function (data) {
                                var name = data.split(" ");

                    $("#fname").val(name[0]);
                    $("#lname").val(name[1]);   
                            }

            });
 });

        });
```

Then in getname.php file use id posted by the ajax method and fetch the firstname and lastname of the member and echo them separated by space as we are using split on "space" and then set the values of the input fields.